# База данных, Python

Tags: python

Есть код игры тетрис. Нужно подсоединить базу данных к коду. Как вы можете знать, за каждую удаленную линию начисляются очки. Вот фрагмент кода, где это происходит:

[а тут весь код](https://yadi.sk/d/F1H-j5Qc3x2t8Q)

```
def removeFullLines(self):
    numFullLines = 0 # кол-во заполненных линий
    rowsToRemove = []
    for i in range(Board.BoardHeight):
        n = 0
        for j in range(Board.BoardWidth):
            if not self.shapeAt(j, i) == Tetrominoe.NoShape:
                n = n + 1
        if n == 14:
        # n - ширина игрового поля(не в пикселях, а в блоках, ну это не важно)
            rowsToRemove.append(i)
    # ... то что ниже, пока не важно
    #rowsToRemove.reverse()

    #for m in rowsToRemove:
        #for k in range(m, Board.BoardHeight):
            #for l in range(Board.BoardWidth):
                    #self.setShapeAt(l, k, self.shapeAt(l, k + 1))
    # ...

    numFullLines = numFullLines + len(rowsToRemove)
    if numFullLines > 0:
        # по оригинальным правилам тетриса, при заполнений определенного кол-ва линий, даётся определенное кол-во очков
        if numFullLines == 1:
            self.numLinesRemoved = self.numLinesRemoved + numFullLines + 100
            # изначально numLinesRemoved = 0; его в этой части кода нет т.к. он в конструкторе класса
        elif numFullLines == 2:
            self.numLinesRemoved = self.numLinesRemoved + numFullLines + 300
        elif numFullLines == 3:
            self.numLinesRemoved = self.numLinesRemoved + numFullLines + 500
        elif numFullLines == 4:
            self.numLinesRemoved = self.numLinesRemoved + numFullLines + 1500
        # numLinesRemoved хранит количество набранных очков
        self.msg2Statusbar.emit(str('Score: {}'.format(self.numLinesRemoved)))
        # в статус бар, который находится внизу экрана выводится кол-во очков
        self.isWaitingAfterLine = True
        self.curPiece.setShape(Tetrominoe.NoShape)
        self.update()
```

Итак, подскажите, пожалуйста, как хранить в базе данных кол-во очков?
После геймовера нужно сделать так, чтобы вводилось имя, а затем показывался рекорд как то так: "Game over. *ИГРОК* Ваш результат: ...." ну или как-то по-другому

P.s. Я же правильно понимаю, что база данных будет сохранять всё это дело и при следующем запуске программы и не терять эти данные?

P.P.s. Прошу прощения, если не правильно оформил фрагмент кода, я пока осваиваюсь)

Comment: Если нужно сохранять только имя и количество очков, то хватит и текстового файла. База данных для этого будет слишком перебор.

Comment: Это для проекта) Нужно использовать базу данных обязательно, я хз как её ещё можно применить

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать бд sqlite

Допустим у вас в бд будет таблица score

В players будет два столбца, первый name, второй score

Когда игрок проигрывает вы заносите в score его очки, и после введения имя , оно заносится в name в той же строке что и score. Но лучше заносить score после введения имени